# Kafka performance with messages of size in GBs

Tags: apache-kafka

I know kafka performs better with larger messages when message size ranges from bytes to few MBs. But, does the above correlations holds true when you have message size ranges from kilo bytes to gigabytes?

Basically, i have a use case where the producer spits out large messages - i can't break the large message into smaller messages as I need to process it atomically.

Answer (score 2):

Consider not putting the data into the message. As in: dump the message main body somewhere else and send a link or reference numbers around. Ignore Kafka for a moment - if you start distributing messages of this size via publish/subscribe you will quite fast and easily overload any sensible network and processing infrastructure. 100g is not a netowrk most companies have. Even 10G is a problem. 1Gb takes 10 seconds on an EMPTY 1gigabit link to transfer.

I would challenge the sensibility of any architecture pushing data around like this.